# prolog successor state axiom ERROR: Out of local stack

Tags: prolog, wumpus-world

I am trying to formulate a successor state axiom for an agent that moves (north,south,west,east) in a 4x4 grid. The grid has two obstacles at 1,1 and 2,2 and the initial position of the agent is 3,3. The agent should reach the the teleportal which is in position 1,2 without hitting any obstacles. Here is the code:

```
obstacle(1,1).
obstacle(2,3).
teleportal(1,3).
agent(3,3,s0).
agent(X, Y, result(A,S)):-
   (  agent(X,Y,S), 
      (  A = north, (X=0; (obstacle(X2,Y), X2 is X-1)))
      ;
        (A = south, (X=3; (obstacle(X2,Y), X2 is X+1)));
        (A = west, (Y=0; (obstacle(X,Y2), Y2 is Y-1)));
        (A = east, (Y=3; (obstacle(X,Y2), Y2 is Y+1)))) 
        ;
        (agent(X2, Y, S), A = north, X > 0, X2 is X-1);
        (agent(X2, Y, S), A = south, X < 3, X2 is X+1);
        (agent(X, Y2, S), A = west, Y > 0, Y2 is Y-1);
        (agent(X, Y2, S), A = east, Y < 3, Y2 is Y+1).

escaped(S):- agent(X,Y,S), teleportal(X,Y).
```

When I run escape(S), it gives the following error: Out of local stack

Comment: Please add more details on error / exception you are getting (may be more lines)

Comment: @smilyface this is the only error that I get, no error details are shown

Comment: Please say `listing(agent)` to see how things are actually interpreted

Comment: The  error means you're likely going into an infinite recursion. You could do `trace` to see where the code goes and watch the conditions in variables that might cause it to do that. Also, in the code you show, are you missing a trailing right parenthesis in your predicate?

Comment: @lurker: suffices to look at `listing`

Comment: @false probably. I'm just offering up alternative tools.

Comment: @false thank you. I traced it and it turns out that the agent always tries to move north. The problem is that Prolog uses DFS to implement backward chaining so the program ran forever since the agent will always try to move north.To solve this issue I considered using the built-in predicate call_with_depth_limit.

Comment: @lurker thank you. I traced it and it turns out that the agent always tries to move north. The problem is that Prolog uses DFS to implement backward chaining so the program ran forever since the agent will always try to move north.To solve this issue I considered using the built-in predicate call_with_depth_limit.

Comment: @Noha: First get your code right.

Comment: @NohaSalama - <Trick> Update your post if you have more information from the above comments to get an answer easily. People who want to answer wont look to comments commonly !